# Analytics event code shows up in source code but not in console

Tags: javascript, jquery, google-analytics, umbraco7

I have a problem on an Umbraco website and it completely baffles me.
For Analytics I have added a event code on several download buttons. On most of the buttons it works perfectly, but there is one that is giving me a headache.

When I look at the source code (in Firefox, Chrome and Edge) the code show up fine:

```
<a onClick="ga('send', 'event', { eventCategory: 'Downloads', eventAction: 'Download document', eventLabel: 'Download document'});" href="/media/181927/06_product-overview_en_v07-2017_web.pdf" class="styledbutton css3trans" rel="external">Download</a>
```

But the click does not register and when I inspect the element with F12 it looks like this:

```
<a onclick="this.target='_blank'" href="/media/181927/06_product-overview_en_v07-2017_web.pdf" class="styledbutton css3trans" rel="external" title="Deze link opent in een nieuw venster">Download</a>
```

Does anybody have a clue how this can happen?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Alright, I found the problem. There was indeed a bit of code in my site's global.js file that overwrote my tracking code.

I found it by searching my entire Visual Studio solution with ctlr-shift-f for a line that said:  "this.target='_blank'"

After commenting that part out of the global.js file my tracking code works like it should.

Tnx Eike Pierstorff for pointing me in the right direction

Answer (score 1):

Why in "onclick" have you write "this.target='_blank'"? 
Your code isn't valid (W3C).
The correct and valid way to do this is:

```
<a href="www.example.com" target="_blank"></a>
```

Answer (score 0):

My educated guess would be that you have a script that opens links to media files (or links with the attribute "external") in a new tab my setting the target attribute to `_blank`. It would seem that this script overwrites the existing onclick handler with its own code, mangling the event tracking code in the process.

As I said a guess, but a plausible one.

Comment: Is there a way I could track down the script that overwrites my Analytics code?